# Large number of enthusiast badges awarded in short succession

Tags: support, badges, activity-badges

Recently (a few minutes ago), I noticed that on SO, all but one of the recently awarded badges on the list on the home page were Enthusiast badges. Normally, there are just a few at a time. Was this some sort of huge coincidence, or was this some sort of recalculation? If it was a recalculation, how often do these occur?

I know this is a strange question, but this seemed way too strange to be a coincidence...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would assume it is because it's shortly after midnight UTC time, which means its a new day, but still early enough in the US that there are people likely hanging around and earning the badge. Basically, I wouldn't be surprised if many days around this time there are a bunch of people earning the woot badge.

Comment: Yes, spot on. The cron job for this badge also runs every 300 seconds, which causes a 'flood' every 5 minutes as people visit the site near the start of a new day.

Comment: I would also add, it's likely you see a slew of woot earners around this time tomorrow I believe it is.

Comment: @Ian: how do you know that it fires every 300 seconds?

Comment: I hax, in other words, `SELECT Date, count(*) as Occurrences, (ABS(Date-1246021054)%300) as Offset FROM badges WHERE Name LIKE '%Enthusiast%'  GROUP BY Offset`

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that happens once a day as new people go over the 30-day threshold for the badge.