# Why were a bunch of Necromancer badges were just awarded?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

[alt text http://img148.imageshack.us/img148/743/necromancer.png](http://img148.imageshack.us/img148/743/necromancer.png)

Is this a bug?  This was taken at about 2:37 PM EST

I find the odds of having that many silver badges awarded at once, not likely.

Comment: A question probably got migrated.

Comment: It's the zombie apocalypse!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The badge awards for Necromancer are likely only calculated once a day like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10223/large-number-of-woot-badges-awarded-in-short-succession).

Answer (score 1):

This happens when a badge hasn't run for a while (it's a bit of a random chance for some more expensive badges), or a badge was just corrected in code and is awarding for occurrences it missed before the bug was fixed.