# what is the time lapse between achieving a tag badge and it being awarded?

Tags: discussion, tags, badges

Today I've passed 400 non-cw upvotes for answers in Java (well according to my [GM script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20896/im-not-appearing-in-the-all-time-list-for-java-is-this-a-bug/21623#21623) I have anyway), if there is not a bug in my script's tallying, I believe that qualifies for the silver badge. As yet I've not received the badge.

I assume there is some batch process that does the counting and awards the badge, does anyone know what the interval between checks is?

Update: For future reference I just got the badge at 10:00 am UTC, about 12 hours after I passed the threshold.

Comment: Duplicate, "When are topic badges awarded?" http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20906/when-are-topic-badges-awarded - however, the answer was inconclusive.

Comment: @Greg, yes this is a duplicate. I've voted to close it

Answer (score 9):

Some badges (mostly the ones which can be awarded more than once) are awarded fairly quickly once you meet the criteria.  Things like Nice Question, Enlightened, and the like.  These are probably awarded from within the main system, typically triggered by voting activity.

Other badges (mostly the ones which can only be awarded once, like the specialist badges) are awarded by a background process which appears to run only once a day.  According to TheTXI (comment below), this seems to happen at 0:00 UTC (at least on meta), but since we don't have an official word on this, it's hard to say whether it's the same for all sites or is consistent.  However, it's safe to say that after 24 hours, if you still don't have your badge, something is amiss.

Comment: From personal experience here on Meta, the tag badges I believe are awarded after the server rolls over to the next day when the badge process runs, 0:00 UTC

Comment: Thanks, I've incorporated that info into my answer. :)

Comment: Hmm it's now tomorrow and still no badge

Comment: @Rich: Hmm, so it's not particularly consistent.  Weird.  Maybe there are different processes for different badges?

Answer (score 4):

I seem to remember that this process runs every night.

[Searching for evidence]

**EDIT**

I could not find any evidence to back me up

In [question #88](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge/898#898) Jeff refers to the badge background process, but I couldn't find any place where it mentions when it runs.

Comment: No mention of when it runs but this post/comments talks about a cron job running periodically: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10223/large-number-of-woot-badges-awarded-in-short-succession

Answer (score 0):

Last I waited for a badge it seemed to show up within minutes. I wouldn't be surprised if it varies based on badge, though.