# Tag Badge Grant Lag?

Tags: discussion, tags, badges, tag-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the time lapse between achieving a tag badge and it being awarded?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23080/what-is-the-time-lapse-between-achieving-a-tag-badge-and-it-being-awarded)

(I couldn't resist with the title.)

What's the lag between getting the X number of votes required to get a tag badge, and actually being granted it?  Is there any difference in terms of the delay between an upvote putting you over the edge, and a retagging?

Comment: Check out [what is the time lapse between achieving a tag badge and it being awarded?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23080/what-is-the-time-lapse-between-achieving-a-tag-badge-and-it-being-awarded). As noted in [the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23080/what-is-the-time-lapse-between-achieving-a-tag-badge-and-it-being-awarded/23089#23089), certain badges such as the tag badges do not get rewarded all that often, so they run on a much slower period of update rather than as immediate as the quick ones. Usually it arrives within 48 hours of hitting the threshold.