# Could the granting lag for each badge be added to the FAQ?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges, faq-update-request

With [so many questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug+badges) questioning why Badge X hasn't been awarded yet, would it be possible to add a line to each badge description:

- This badge will be awarded within an hour of meeting the criteria
- This badge will be awarded within 48 hours of meeting the criteria
- This badge will be awarded within seven days of meeting the criteria

Or perhaps at least add a question / entry into [the Badge FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work):

*The following badges are awarded within five minutes of meeting the criteria:*

[badge:Nice Question] [Nice Answer]...

*The following badges are awarded within 48 hours of meeting the criteria:*

...

This would be most helpful in responding to questions like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97924/tag-badge-grant-lag) as well as the many bug requests about un-awarded badges.

Comment: Under-commit and over-deliver: [six to eight weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) for all badges.

Comment: I think this sort of information is especially important for certain tags: [Tenacious & Unsung Hero](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57696)

Comment: Doesn't *anyone* like to be surprised? Did'ja all wake up on Christmas morning knowing exactly what was in those boxes? Was it a major let-down for you when you got a green Power Ranger instead of a purple one? Did'ja... make your folks sign a contract the next year?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There actually isn't a *guarantee* of a time period for any badge that isn't run on every cycle.  What happens is this:

- Every 5 minutes we run a badge grant for local database-based badges.

  - For most badges (simple queries that aren't time/resource intensive against the DB), they get run *every* time.
  - For the others more expensive badges we assign a frequency at which they run.
- Every hour we run what we call "code badges", that make remote API calls to chat, meta, etc to get their data.  Examples include [Quorum](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/900/quorum) and [Talkative](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/884/talkative).

Now this "frequency" is more of a probability, there's a 1/n chance the badge will run *that time*.  We could have a run that assigns *all* SQL badges, or *none of them*, it's all statistics.  The [law of large numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) dictates that *on average* the badges will get run with that % chance of frequency, but looking at a narrow time period (as would be required for a FAQ type entry), it's much more random.  Giving a *specific* time (or even an approximate one real for these badges would be disingenuous, so we don't document it anywhere that I'm aware of.

Based on your comment though, I will say the probability for Tenacious and Unsung Hero running on any given badge cycle is 1 in 4.

Comment: Hey, I'm a statistician!! :o) This is a perfect explanation for me though.  Could we just link to your answer from the faq?  I realize that not everyone will take pulling out the WLLN, but the wikipedia link is quite reasonable or we could point them to questions on cross-validated for more explanation.  :O)

Comment: @MTibbits - possibly, or some generic text around the frequency like I explain above...of course this is subject to change.  We're actually working on FAQ content now, so I'll pass this suggestion on to our community team :)