# Clarification of the tag-wiki entry for [tag:faq-proposed]?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits, tag-wiki

The tag [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed)'s [wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/faq-proposed/info) states that the [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) is for:

> Questions that are proposing new or amended entries for the FAQ should use this tag.

But there is also another tag: [faq-update-request](/questions/tagged/faq-update-request) which has no wiki but sounds like it would be a better fit for questions [like mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97948)?

Should the tag wiki for [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) be updated to remove the 'amended entries' in like of the [faq-updated-request](/questions/tagged/faq-updated-request) tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) is for the Community maintained FAQ that is stored here at MSO under the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag.

[faq-update-request](/questions/tagged/faq-update-request) is for updates to the basic FAQ located at `/faq` for all sites, such as [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq).

Your question sounds like it should be [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed), as `/faq` is reserved for the basics and for other essential things—the badge frequency cycle, while important, is not essential to using the site.

Comment: Of course it would help if I linked to right tag.... Makes sense to me. I proposed an updated tag-wiki for [meta-tag:faq-update-request].