# Badge granting cycles?

Tags: discussion, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could the granting lag for each badge be added to the FAQ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97948/could-the-granting-lag-for-each-badge-be-added-to-the-faq)

Is there a list of badges that are granted (nearly) immediately vs. badges that are granted after a calculation point or process runs?  Specifically despite my reputation surpassing 200 on SO, I didn't gain yearling until sometime in the night (and then gained it twice -- go figure), so I'm wondering if it would be helping to document or explain the processing.  I've read the similar question about this, but the accepted answer doesn't seem to jive with what is observed.  Admittedly if it's a 1/n probability then you could justify a nearly infinite delay, but that seems like it would be a bad precedent to set.  We're all feedback driven creatures, delaying that too much makes it pointless.

Comment: [Check out this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97948/could-the-granting-lag-for-each-badge-be-added-to-the-faq/97951#97951) (I previously begged for this info)

Comment: yeah, that was my reference to the 1/n similar question.  Nick's answer while accurate is unsatisfying.  If the "every time" vs. "occasionally" list could be clarified, that helps set expectations appropriately.  Failing to meet them is optional.

Comment: Indeed.  Why make it probabilistic at all?

Comment: I can understand that, although probabilistic is probably (HA!) the wrong concept.  More likely the queries are judged to be too taxing to run frequently so they're round-robin-ed to avoid slowing the systems too much.  I'd like to think there *is* a guarantee that the query will run eventually, but I've no proof of that (shockingly).

Comment: Why are you so worried about this? Badges are supposed to be a pleasant surprise, not something that you expect and wait in anticipation for.

Comment: Probably because many of us are detail oriented, performance driven feedback junkies.  I mean you can't set goals then not expect people to attempt to achieve those goals.  In this case, the goals have rules that some of us want to understand better, if for no other reason than an unhealthy level of curiosity.

Comment: These are not "goals", they're prizes. Set goals for reputation, not badges.

Comment: Got to disagree.  Some are goals.  Strunk and White/Copy Editor, Fanatic/Enthusiast and others are totally things you set out to do.