# Are questions tagged with synonyms ignored for tag badges?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, badges, tag-synonyms

About 36 hours ago, I reached the threshold for the bronze tag badge for formal-languages on cs.SE (see [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/98/raphael?tab=tags) for the current standings). However, I have not yet been awarded the badge. [Earlier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23080/what-is-the-time-lapse-between-achieving-a-tag-badge-and-it-being-awarded) [posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97924/tag-badge-grant-lag) suggest that some lag is normal, but apparently some (UTC-)overnight process should do the job, of which two should have run since then.

Somebody suggested in chat that synonyms may be the reason. And true enough, there is a synonym [fl.formal-languages](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/formal-languages/synonyms). As far as  I can remember, that tag has never existed on cs.SE (therefore no merge); it has been created purely so that thus tagged questions migrated over from cstheory.SE are tagged nicely on cs.SE without us having to lift a finger.

I could track down four answers with 16 upvotes on questions that took this migration path; that's not quite enough to explain the effect (as I have 117 upvotes in total and received no votes today yet). But then, I can not look deeper into this; maybe somebody *did* tag a cs.SE-original question with the synonym?

I expect that deeper analysis of the issue (what stuff was flagged how when, exactly when did I reach the threshold, ...) needs more than mere mod powers. So, is there something to this or am I just not patient enough?

**Edit:** Morning of May 25th: two votes on formal-languages on the 24th, another night gone by, still no badge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tag itself doesn't qualify yet, there aren't enough questions tagged "formal-languages" (81 right now). According to [What are tag badges? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63835/what-are-tag-badges-how-do-they-work):

> A tag must appear on a minimum of 100 questions to be considered for tag badges.

Comment: Doh. It's even on the badge page: "If enough votes are earned in a tag with 100+ total questions, the badge will be automatically created and awarded." My mistake.