# Time before badge is awarded?

Tags: discussion, badges

I recently reached 600 votes on questions, with at least 25% of my total votes being on questions. This effectively earns me the gold Electorate badge. I have not earned it yet.

I'm not complaining, but is there a specified time between the qualification for the badge being reached and the actual awarding of the badge? Or is it just the arbitrary time it takes for the server to go through and check for badge qualifications?

Comment: I've been eligible for months and haven't got it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just be patient.  I can't immediately find a good duplicate to mark this as, but the badges are awarded by batch processes that only run on a periodic basis for performance reasons.  I'd wait at least a day before being concerned.

There doesn't seem to be any hard evidence detailing this process, but the best I found is within and linked to from [what is the time lapse between achieving a tag badge and it being awarded?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23080/what-is-the-time-lapse-between-achieving-a-tag-badge-and-it-being-awarded).

(This seems to be a frequently enough asked question, that it would be nice if it could be put into a FAQ somewhere, or all existing evidence consolidated into its own community wiki answer somewhere.  Things seem to vary *slightly* depending upon the badge type, etc. - so any consolidated answer should take this into account.)

Comment: The linked answer states that this process runs every day at 0:00 UTC. I will assume that it is correct, so thank you for your answer.

Comment: It is not correct, as I just received my new badge. I will keep your answer as correct, however, because you did not specify the time.

Comment: @DevinGund 0:00 UTC is more likely to be for the batch process that awards badges on Meta SO, not the main site (as the linked post suggests). I usually get my badges a couple of hours after the conditions are met, but there is no point in knowing the exact time, and that most certainly varies per badge _and_ per site.