# I couldn't get the Informed badge? How to get it?

Tags: support, badges, tour

I am new on Stack Overflow, I tried to get more badges and reputation.

I noticed the 'Informed Badge'. It says that it will get if we read the entire About page.

I tried it. I read the entire About page. But the badge doesn't appear in my profile.

What are the other easiest badges I can get?

Comment: You might also want to read [Time before badge is awarded?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119698/time-before-badge-is-awarded)

Comment: I have rolled back your most recent edit. Please do not vandalize your own posts.

Comment: @senshin how would you get recover my old question? it is amazing.

Comment: @user3705625 We can see the edit history of a question and roll back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The badges that are easy to earn are:

- Autobiographer - Completed "About Me" section of user profile
- Informed - Read the entire about page. **NOTE:** This is not available on **meta** sites.
- Editor - First edit

Fairly easy to earn:

- Teacher - Answered first question with a score of 1 or more.
- Student - Asked first question with score of 1 or more
- Supporter - First up vote *you need to earn 15 reputation*
- Critic - First down vote *you need 125 reputation*

Re the "Informed" badge. If you scrolled all the way to the bottom of the about page on the main site it will have told you that you'd earned the badge.